# Reading line by line from a text file in Perl and case folding each line

Tags: perl

I am trying to read a text file in Perl. For each line, I would like to split the sentence into its words fold the case before processing it any further. I am not sure about the syntax for folding case when reading from a file.

```
while ($line = <$fh>){
    @words = split /\s+/, $line;
    foreach my $word (@words){
        $hashCounter{$word}++;
}
```

Comment: `while ( <$fh> ) { $hashCounter{$_}++ for map {fc} split; };` should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`fc()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fc.html),

```
$hashCounter{ fc($word) }++;
```

From [`perldoc -f fc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fc.html)

> Returns the casefolded version of EXPR. This is the internal function implementing the \F escape in double-quoted strings.
>   Casefolding is the process of mapping strings to a form where case differences are erased; comparing two strings in their casefolded form is effectively a way of asking if two strings are equal, regardless of case.

Comment: When I use $hashCounter{fc(word)}++; I get the error of "Undefined subroutine &main::fc called at filename.pl line 13, <$fh> line 1."

Comment: @SagarSamtani you perl is older than v5.16. You can use `lc()` for older perl versions.